# How to disable validation in Plumier

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plumier

I'm in a complex situation and need to do validation manually inside the controller. I couldn't find how to disable automatic validation in the documentation. Is there workaround to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plumier validation works based on controller's parameter type. If you provide `any` parameter type, validation will be skipped.

```js
class AnimalController {
   @route.post("")
   save(@bind.body() data:any) {
       // use any data type
       // data validation will be skipped
   }
}
```

Internally Plumier uses [typedconverter](https://github.com/plumier/typedconverter) to validate the request body, so you can use that inside your controller too.

BTW, you can apply custom validator on any parameter, technically you can do anything inside custom validator like you do inside controller. Custom validator better for code separation and reusability.